# Use numbers starting with 0 in a variable in php

Tags: php

Hi i need to save a 010 number in $number and if i do like this php will remove the starting 0

```
    $number = 010
```

And echo of this will return 10 how can i make it not to remove the initial 0

BR 
Martin

Comment: and what is the result in `echo` ? is it `8`

Comment: @Martin Alderlöf Have you even try to echo $number to see what it would it display ? It would not display 10 , it would display 8 ! It is because a number starting with 0 is considered octal .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use it as a String:

```
$number = '010';
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `str_pad()` function.

```
echo str_pad('10',3,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php

Answer (score 4):

Do remember that ***numbers starting with 0 can also be treated as octal number notation by the PHP compiler***, hence if you want to work with decimal numbers, simply use:

```
$num = '010';
```

This way the number is saved, can be stored in the database and manipulated like any other number. (Thx to the fact that PHP is very loosely typed language.)

**Another method to use would be:**

Save number as `$num = 10;`

Later while printing the value you can use [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php), like:

```
sprintf("%03d", $i);
```

This will print your number in 3 digit format, hence 0 will be added automatically.

**Another method:**

```
<?php
$num = 10;
$zerofill = 3;

echo str_pad($num, $zerofill, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

/* Returns the wanted result of '010' */
?>
```

You can have a look at the various options available to you and make a decision. Each of the method given above will give you a correct output.