# Why does $variable = 0759 give out 61?

Tags: php, variables

I don't know how to google this one out so I an asking it here. Why does it happen that when I declare a variable `$something = 0759` that it turns into 61. I know the answer must be very simple so please forgive my sillyness.

Comment: would you please provide your code. what you are trying to do?

Comment: What is the purpose of the leading zero? Are you meaning to have the value as a string?

Comment: Its an [octal number](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Comment: I have no clue why this question is downvoted, it is legit, 100%

Comment: @dev4092 Read the question and understand, don't just glance the questions and think, hey, no grey block with codes, lets shoot a comment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is an Integer literal, you declare a octal number with a leading zero.

```
$something = 0759; // octal
```

The octal numeral system is a base-8 number system. 
You can only use Numbers between 0-7 (other numbers are discarded).

```
$a = 0759; 
$b = 075;
var_dump($a==$b);
// bool(true)
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

You could skip the zeros with ltrim.

```
 $a = ltrim("0759", 0); 
 echo $a; // 759
 // and reformat as suggested with str_pad or printf
 echo str_pad($a, 4, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
```

Comment: 0759 == 075 (because no "9" in octal system) == 61 in decimal

Answer (score 9):

### Why does it happen

In PHP (and most programming languages), numbers preceding with a `0` is treated as an [octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal). It's a base-8 number system and has digits from 1-7.

Octal 0759 is equivalent to octal 075 (9 is discarded because there's no 9 in the octal system). Octal 075 is equivalent to decimal 61. PHP actually stores the number as octal, but when output with `print` / `echo` it's always in decimal, so 075 becomes 61.

### The Conversion

See Wikipedia on [Octal to Decimal conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal#Octal_to_decimal_conversion). But this should give you a basic idea:

(075)<sub>8</sub> = (0 x 8^2) + (7 x 8^1) + (5 x 8^0) 
(075)<sub>8</sub> = 0 + 56 + 5
(075)<sub>8</sub> = 61

Basically:

```
7 * 8 = 56
5 * 1 =  5
       ====
        61
```

### How to resolve this issue

**Simply store the numbers as integers / strings and format them on output.**

Using [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf):

```
echo sprintf('%04d', $number); // 0759
```

Using [`str_pad()`](http://php.net/str_pad):

```
echo str_pad($number, 4, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT); // 0759
```

If you really want to preserve the leading zero, then store it as a string:

```
$number = '0759';
```

Comment: @FDL: It was removed quickly... :) [FGITW problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem) :)

Comment: You can confirm this with a pretty simple test: `(int) base_convert(759, 8, 10) === 0759; // True`

Comment: I was looking on how to save it as 0759 as well. Thanks @AmalMurali

Comment: @Bazinga777 If you're looking to pad a variable with leading zeroes, you may want to look at `str_pad()` too!

Answer (score 2):

Numbers starting with 0 can be treated as octal number notation by the PHP compiler.

You can find more details here:
[Use numbers starting with 0 in a variable in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19354208/use-numbers-starting-with-0-in-a-variable-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

When you assign a number to avariable starting with 0, its assumed to be octal, in your case (0759) 9 is not an octal digit, hence ignored, 75 octal converted to decimal is 61.

Answer (score 1):

number starting with 0 is octal but in octal you can use 0-7 not 9 so 0759 will cast to 075 and 075 in octal is 61 in decimal